# RTSP address to Yale WIPC-303w camera

Tags: rtsp

In order to use the Yale PTZ WIPC-303w camera with NVRs or simply stream the video to eg. VLC the RTSP address to it is required. How to get it or what is it?

Ability to stream the video from the cam would make it possible to use it as any other IP cam in NVR like ZoneMinder, Shinobi, Kerberos.io or iSpy.

Answer (score 0):

The RTSP address is:

```
rtsp://IPADDRESS:88/videoMain
```

The RTSP client (eg. VLC) will then ask for username and password of the cam.

Then to get the video stream in VLC on linux the command line is:

```bsh
vlc "rtsp://IPADDRESS:88/videoMain"
```

And the ONVIF address for this camera is:

```
http://user:password@<ip_address_of_camera>/onvif/device_service
```

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible to almost fully control the camera using the ONVIF protocol. This requires the ONVIF functionality to be first enabled in the camera by visiting the camera's address on https eg. https://IPADDRESS/ , logging in to it and enabling ONVIF in the settings. Unfortunately only IE (Internet Explorer) browser can be used to enable this setting initially.

After enabling ONVIF the camera should be discoverable in applications like:
OWLR (Android) or ONVIF Device Manager (Windows).

Comment: For example using "ONVIF Device Manager" it's actually possible to change the stream resolution from the default 720p to 960p.